# Check if unicode value is in Erlang binary string?

Tags: string, encoding, binary, erlang, default

I came across questions on how to find a value in a list and I am also aware of `lists:member/2`.

- [Erlang lists:index_of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459152/erlang-listsindex-of-function)
- [How to Search for an item in a List in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673219/how-to-search-for-an-item-in-a-list-in-erlang)

Is there something like `lists:member/2` binary strings? I need to check if a value is present in the binary. I imagine something like this:

```
value_in_binary(<<"Some random data">>, <<"d">>). 
%> true
```

Does anything like this exist? If not, how would I go about implementing a function like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out binary:match/2,3. For example

```
1> binary:match(<<"some random data">>, <<"d">>).
{8,1}
2> binary:match(<<"some random data">>, <<"z">>).
nomatch
```