# How to get element from an erlang list?

Tags: erlang

I have a list
`List = [ins_appServer_APP02@mdiaz,ins_appServer_APP04@mdiaz]`.

and I have an atom that comes as a parameter: 
`AppServerAtom = ins_appServerAPP02@mdiaz`

I need help to search in `List` the element that match with `AppServerAtom`

It is possible to do this with Erlang?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Search for an item in a List in Erlang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673219/how-to-search-for-an-item-in-a-list-in-erlang)

Comment: what do you need as a result?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AppServerAtom = ins_appServer_APP02@mdiaz` ?

Comment: A. Sarid : I need to get the element that match with AppServerAtom

Comment: P_A, ty i resolve it with duplicate as you say. Ty so much

Answer (score 3):

Use `lists:member/2`:

```
List = ['ins_appServer_APP02@mdiaz', 'ins_appServer_APP04@mdiaz'],
case lists:member('ins_appServer_APP02@mdiaz', List) of
  true -> do_something_when_true();
  false -> do_something_when_false()
end.
```

See http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists:mem#member/2 in the Erlang function reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the matched element, you can use [lists:filter](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2)

```
lists:filter(fun(X) -> X == AppServerAtom end, List).
```

If  you just want check the element is in the List, you can use [lists:member](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2)